# User editable template/view - Node.js, Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, templates

Has anyone here an experience with writting an application, where the user is allowed to edit a template of his "profile" online? I mean custom css, html and js - like Tumblr allows that.

What is the best and secure way to do that? Is it better to store the template in a database or in a file?

I am trying to implement this feature with node.js and mongodb, but your experience from other frameworks/languages are welcome too!

Comment: Keep it in a database. That's the only way. (where database refers to a location independent storage mechanism tied to a key value for the information you need to retrieve ~  A filesystem could also be a database for purposes of this answer. You still need a way to associate the key value to the data itself.) Most sites give you several fields that you can modify, and inject one as HTML, one as CSS, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I would like to create one "text-editor like" textarea to allow user to add or modify anything in his "profile" template (from css to js). I know it is quite unsecure, but if my app provides a template API to access just certain things, I hope there wouldn't be a security problem, or am I wrong?

Comment: I am still completely lost as to what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I posted my comment prematurely. I'm just interested, how Tumblr (for example) implemented its Theme system safely...

Comment: Hi @MartinSnajdr did you resolve this? I'm interested in doing something similar. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @doup. Well, I did not. But I realized that the security is not so important as I thought. If you use a templating system (like Tumblr's Liquid) you can control all the available variables and replace everything forbidden. And I think it's better to use database to store the template.